# How to match an array in Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

begginners question in haskell, when trying to process JSON data.

I've got a simple file named *kk* with the following contents:

```
{
 "id": 123,
 "name": "Test1"
}
```

And I am successfully reading and parsing it with the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

data Test = Test { id       ∷ Integer
                 , name     ∷ String
                 } deriving (Show)


process v = Test <$>
                 (v .: "id")       <*>
                 (v .: "name")


instance FromJSON Test where
  parseJSON (Object o) = process o
  parseJSON (Array  a)  = mzero
  parseJSON _ = mzero

main = do
    src ← readFile "kk"
    let t = decode (BS.pack src) ∷ Maybe Test
    print t
```

However, I cannot seem to determine how should I process the file if it is an array, meaning:

```
[{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Test1"
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Test2"
}]
```

How can I fold or otherwise iterate the array case?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, have you tried `let t = decode (BS.pack src) ∷ Maybe [Test]`?

Comment: I was so sure that I must match the *array*, it never occured to me... that's it! Tks

Comment: @dave4420: you may as well put that as an answer so that the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
let t = decode (BS.pack src) :: Maybe [Test]
```